# localhost:3000 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, localhost

I think I messed something up big time. I have used this command `rails new app --database=postgresql` for a long time and I was a happy boy. But today I forgot to generate an app to use `postgresql`. Now each time I run `rails new app --database=postgresql` and go to `http://localhost:3000/`, I get greeted with

> 500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this
>   website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the
>   web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

I checked the logs and I have something like this:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:11:56 +0200

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "toy_development" does not exist
):
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in connect'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/siaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (15.2ms)
```

So then I fire up `psql` to create a database called `toy_development`. `toy` is the name of my app btw. After create that database. I try again to load `localhost` in the browser. And then now I get this:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:18:17 +0200

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/siaw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/siaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (13.8ms)
```

I need some help here. :)

Comment: For the future, `bundle exec rake db:create` - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#db

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 'parse\_query' error on server in brand new app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925008/rails-parse-query-error-on-server-in-brand-new-app)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Bundler updated my version of `rack` to `rack (1.6.3)` so I changed it back manually to `rack (1.6.2)` in `Gemfile.lock`. This should keep things working for now till the Rails team fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned you are using postgresql as database rails by default does not create it database .
it would not have been the case if you would have used sqlite3 as database

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

then,

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: do not fire up psql to create a database, toy_development you self let rails take care of it by using rake db:create and migrate

Comment: the solution had nothing to do with postgresql. i fixed this already myself :). but thank you.